# Allowing the "Enter" key to press the submit button, as opposed to only using MouseClick

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I'm learning Swing class now and everything about it. I've got this toy program I've been putting together that prompts for a name and then presents a JOptionPane with the message "You've entered (Your Name)".
The submit button I use can only be clicked on, but I'd like to get it to work with the Enter button too. I've tried adding a KeyListener, as is recommended in the Java book I'm using (Eventful Java, Bruce Danyluk and Murtagh).

[image: NamePrompt]
[image]

This is my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class NamePrompt extends JFrame{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    String name;

    public NamePrompt(){

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JLabel enterYourName = new JLabel("Enter Your Name Here:");
        JTextField textBoxToEnterName = new JTextField(21);
        JPanel panelTop = new JPanel();
        panelTop.add(enterYourName);
        panelTop.add(textBoxToEnterName);

        JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
        submit.addActionListener(new SubmitButton(textBoxToEnterName));
        submit.addKeyListener(new SubmitButton(textBoxToEnterName));
        JPanel panelBottom = new JPanel();
        panelBottom.add(submit);

        //Add panelTop to JFrame
        add(panelTop, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(panelBottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //JFrame set-up
        setTitle("Name Prompt Program");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);


    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NamePrompt promptForName = new NamePrompt();
        promptForName.setVisible(true); 
    }


}
```

And this is the actionListener, keyListener class:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class SubmitButton implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    JTextField nameInput;


    public SubmitButton(JTextField textfield){
        nameInput = textfield;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent submitClicked) {

        Component frame = new JFrame();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame , "You've Submitted the name " + nameInput.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
        Component frame = new JFrame();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame , "You've Submitted the name " + nameInput.getText());

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Next time, please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can easily narrow it down.

Comment: @Marvin this was answered six years ago

Comment: Oh. Didn't see the timestamp :P

Answer (score 134, accepted):

There is a simple trick for this. After you constructed the frame with all it buttons do this:

```
frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(submitButton);
```

For each frame, you can set a default button that will automatically listen to the Enter key (and maybe some other event's I'm not aware of). When you hit enter in that frame, the ActionListeners their `actionPerformed()` method will be invoked.

---

And the problem with your code as far as I see is that your dialog pops up every time you hit a key, because you didn't put it in the if-body. Try changing it to this:

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
        System.out.println("Hello");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , "You've Submitted the name " + nameInput.getText());
    }

}
```

---

**UPDATE:** I found what is wrong with your code. You are adding the key listener to the Submit button instead of to the TextField. Change your code to this:

```
SubmitButton listener = new SubmitButton(textBoxToEnterName);
textBoxToEnterName.addActionListener(listener);
submit.addKeyListener(listener);
```

Comment: It works! Can you explain why this works? Also, what if I wanted the Submit button to be pressed with the Spacebar? (i.e. if there were more than one button)

Comment: Clear enough? Glad to help :)

Comment: Actually, before I implemented your solution, the dialog wasn't popping up for any key (even Enter). What was wrong?

Comment: Also, it should output "Hello", when I press enter but it's not.

Comment: OK i see what's going on... the 'this.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(submit);' eliminates the need for the KeyListener. But can you tell me how to actually pass the key (let's say it's not the "default" enter, but some other key) to the listener class?

Comment: Very simple solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

You can use the top level containers root pane to set a default button, which will allow it to respond to the enter.

```
SwingUtilities.getRootPane(submitButton).setDefaultButton(submitButton);
```

This, of course, assumes you've added the button to a valid container ;)

**UPDATED**

This is a basic example using the `JRootPane#setDefaultButton` and key bindings API

```
public class DefaultButton {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DefaultButton();
    }

    public DefaultButton() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JButton button;
        private JLabel label;
        private int count;

        public TestPane() {

            label = new JLabel("Press the button");
            button = new JButton("Press me");

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            add(label, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(button, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JButton("No Action Here"), gbc);

            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    doButtonPressed(e);
                }

            });

            InputMap im = button.getInputMap(WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
            ActionMap am = button.getActionMap();

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0), "spaced");
            am.put("spaced", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    doButtonPressed(e);
                }

            });

        }

        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            SwingUtilities.getRootPane(button).setDefaultButton(button);
        }

        protected void doButtonPressed(ActionEvent evt) {
            count++;
            label.setText("Pressed " + count + " times");
        }

    }

}
```

This of course, assumes that the component with focus does not consume the key event in question (like the second button consuming the <kbd>space</kbd> or <kbd>enter</kbd> keys

Answer (score 2):

In the ActionListener Class you can simply add

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource()==textField){
        textButton.doClick();
    }
    else if (event.getSource()==textButton) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 switch(KEYEVENT.getKeyCode()){
      case KeyEvent.VK_ENTER:
           // I was trying to use case 13 from the ascii table.
           //Krewn Generated method stub... 
           break;
 }
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation for why it does so.

Answer (score 0):

Without a frame this works for me:

```
JTextField tf = new JTextField(20);
tf.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
       SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(e.getComponent()).dispose();
    }
  }
});
String[] options = {"Ok", "Cancel"};
int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
    null, tf, "Enter your message", 
    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
    null,
    options,0);

message = tf.getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't the best way to do it, but right click the button in question, events, key, key typed. This is a simple way to do it, but reacts to any key

Answer (score 0):

```
textField_in = new JTextField();
textField_in.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println(arg0.getExtendedKeyCode());
        if (arg0.getKeyCode()==10) {
            String name = textField_in.getText();
            textField_out.setText(name);
        }

    }

});
textField_in.setBounds(173, 40, 86, 20);
frame.getContentPane().add(textField_in);
textField_in.setColumns(10);
```