# Calling ActionEvent from within KeyEvent or any other listener

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener, keylistener

basically, i want that when user presses ENTER key (checked by its ASCII), the ActionEvent object should be created and its actionPerformed should be called, i.e. to fire my own action event . please provide the required syntax
thnx ! :

Comment: From what to what?  What infrastructure do you have? How are listeners registered?

Comment: i have a simple login page where user enters his name and password
there is a login button which user can user to login. frame and textfields are registered to keylisteners.

i want that when enter key i pressed, i should call ActionEvent manually so that control is tranferred to actionPerformed and it is treated as if login button was pressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each frame, you can set a default button that will automatically listen to the Enter key .When you hit enter in that frame, actionPerformed() method will be invoked.

```
frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(Button);
```

See this:-

[Allowing the "Enter" key to press the submit button, as opposed to only using MouseClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731710/allowing-the-enter-key-to-press-the-submit-button-as-opposed-to-only-using-mo)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html#setDefaultButton%28javax.swing.JButton%29

with regards

ajay

Answer (score 3):

*"i should call ActionEvent manually so that control is tranferred to actionPerformed"*

No, you shouldn't.  You shouldn't be using `KeyListener`s on text fields either.  Simply add a `ActionListener` to the fields if you are interested in knowing when the user "actions" the field.

You can also use [`JRootPane#setDefaultButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html#setDefaultButton%28javax.swing.JButton%29) which can trigger the button when ever the UI specific activation event occurs

Comment: I have no idea as to what happens when action listener is added to a textfield. please explain that

Comment: Take a look at [How to use text fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) and [How to write an action listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html).  Basically, when a user "actions" a field (normally by pressing the enter key) all the registered action listeners are notified.  You can also use `JButton#doClick` to programmatically click a button

Answer (score 0):

use like this if your frame have many buttons.
check your key ascii and determine it is ENTER or ESC.
and use this code

```
ok.doClick(); or cancel.doClick();
```

ok,cancel are buttons, that actions automatically invoke.