# Adding a simple Enter key functionality to my program in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, keyboard, enter

I have a little Java program fully working. And I would like to make the "Enter" key working when I enter a pin Code. As I am writing this post, I can only click on the button to make it work, so I'd like to add this simple functionality without changing all the code.

This is the reason of my post, because I have found several links for it, but none of them corresponds to my situation, knowing that I already have a code working. I need to adapt what I have found there :

[Allowing the "Enter" key to press the submit button, as opposed to only using MouseClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731710/allowing-the-enter-key-to-press-the-submit-button-as-opposed-to-only-using-mo)
http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html
http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-swing-tutorials/3171-jbutton-enter-key-keyboard-action.html
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0253.html

The fact that they're all showing solution from nohting does not help me because I can not use what they did in my own program.

[image: Enter key]

As you can see, this is the "OK" button I need to be clicked or pressed by "Enter"

Here's my code, what do you suggest to have the Enter key working?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JPanel container = new JPanel();
    private JPasswordField p1 = new JPasswordField(4);
    private JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter Pin: ");
    private JButton b = new JButton("OK");


    public Main() {
        this.setTitle("NEEDS");
        this.setSize(300, 500);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        container.setBackground(Color.white);
        container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        container.add(p1);
        JPanel top = new JPanel();

        PlainDocument document =(PlainDocument)p1.getDocument();

        b.addActionListener(new BoutonListener());

        top.add(label);
        top.add(p1);
        p1.setEchoChar('*');
        top.add(b);


        document.setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter(){

            @Override
            public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
                String string =fb.getDocument().getText(0, fb.getDocument().getLength())+text;

                if(string.length() <= 4)
                super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }
        });

        this.setContentPane(top);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    class BoutonListener implements ActionListener {
        private final AtomicInteger nbTry = new AtomicInteger(0);
        ArrayList<Integer> pins = readPinsData(new File("bdd.txt"));

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (nbTry.get() > 2) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Pin blocked due to 3 wrong tries");
                return;
            }
            final String passEntered=p1.getText().replaceAll("\u00A0", "");
            if (passEntered.length() != 4) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Pin must be 4 digits");
                return;
            }
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Checking...");
            //System.out.println("Checking...");
            SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    boolean authenticated = false;
                    ImageIcon imgAngry = new ImageIcon("angry.png");
                    ImageIcon imgHappy = new ImageIcon("happy.png");

                    if (pins.contains(Integer.parseInt(passEntered))) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Pin correct", "Good Pin", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, imgHappy);
                        authenticated = true;
                    }

                    if (!authenticated) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Pin", "Wrong Pin", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, imgAngry);
                        nbTry.incrementAndGet();
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            };
            worker.execute();
        }

    }

    // Reading bdd.txt file
    static public ArrayList<Integer> readPinsData(File dataFile) {
        final ArrayList<Integer> data=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dataFile));
            String line;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    try {
                        data.add(Integer.parseInt(line));
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.err.printf("error parsing line '%s'\n", line);
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                reader.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("error:"+e.getMessage());
        }

        return data;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Main();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to implement a `KeyListener`, is that right?

Comment: Actually all of this is working well. I just want to add a functionnality to make the "Enter" key of my keyboard working on my Button. Right now, this button is only clickable.

Comment: Where should I put this ? That is precisely my problem, I do not know how to adjust my code since I do not add a KeyListener starting from 0.

Comment: *"this is the "OK" button I need to be clicked or pressed by "Enter""*  DYM enter in the button, or the password field, or both?

Comment: Maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731710/allowing-the-enter-key-to-press-the-submit-button-as-opposed-to-only-using-mo) helps you.

Comment: @LostKatana see my post, I already read this one.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, I mean when I click on the button, a JOptionPane appears. I would like to be able to do this by pressing Enter key on my keyboard also.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry...haven't seen that. Just add this line of code:  `p1.addActionListener(new BoutonListener());`

Comment: You should always consult the [official tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) first

Comment: Why do I need to add an ActionListener on p1 and not on the button "b" ? I don't follow.

Comment: you need them on both. One for if the button is pressed and one for if you hit enter in the password field

Comment: What you need to do is to evaluate if there are any side effects I haven't recognized.

Comment: Apparently the program is fully working this way. I don't see any bug.

Comment: Beware: your SwingWorker is incorrect - it **must not** access the view in doInBackground!

Comment: How can I avoid that ?

Comment: _How can I avoid that_ do it elsewhere :) Wondering why you are using a worker at all?

Comment: I needed to let the user have 3 chances while entering his pin Code (just like a credit card). So at firt, I used a do{}while loop, but then I have this code to authenticate if pin was good or not.

Comment: no reason for the worker, you solved that requirement in a different manner, didn't you :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JTextField` (which `JPasswordField` inherits from) provides `ActionListener` support for just this functionality.

```
p1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        b.doClick(); // Re-use the Ok buttons ActionListener...
    }
});
```

Take a look at [How to use text fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) for more details

Comment: You suggest me to create a new actionPerformed method ? Or to add this to the on in my code ?

Comment: Ok I get it, but what does "re-use" mean in this case ? I need to call it a second time ? `b.addActionListener(new BoutonListener());`

Comment: cough .. not the best of solutions because it introduces an unnecessary coupling between several _views_ Instead, use one Action and set it to both the textField and the button. @FlorentP

Answer (score 2):

```
JTextField yourtexfield=new JTextField(8);

yourterxtfield.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
             // your code
      }
});
```

Comment: I don't get your solution ... What do you suggest ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this snipped should guide you, add this code in your class:

```
    @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    b.doClick();
}
```

Comment: My problem is that I tried to adapt some examples of this to my code, and I did not manage to make it work. I needed to see exactly how to add this to my already-made code actually.

Comment: `KeyListener` is poor, actually, it's a bad choice for this.  `JTextField` has an `ActionListener` which is designed for this functionality in a platform independent manner. You can not guarantee the order in which key events are handled and on some platforms, the key event may be consumed before you, meaning it may never reach your listener. Equally, you should never rely on magic numbers.  The `keyCode` may change between platforms

Comment: 1) `KeyListener` is typically the wrong level of functionality for Swing. 2) `if (e.getKeyCode() == 10) {`  Don't use magic numbers. 3) A password field supports an [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#addActionListener-java.awt.event.ActionListener-)..

Comment: I still don't get it. What do you suggest ?

Comment: i thought u want to listen onButtonClick and on onKeyPressed, maybe i understood something wrong.

Comment: ah ok now i understand, sorry guys :D

Answer (score 1):

edit: oh, sorry. Didn't recognize that you are using Swing/AWT. this is a SWT functionality and therefore doesn't help with your problem.

I used the TraverseListener to implement that behavior. You could try this:

```
        p1.addTraverseListener(new TraverseListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTraversed(TraverseEvent e) {
            switch (e.detail) {
              case SWT.TRAVERSE_RETURN:
                doWhateverYourButtonClickDoesHere();
                break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Fleshing out [my comment to @Mad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22657595/203657):

> [invoking `button.doClick()`] is not the best of solutions because it introduces an unnecessary coupling between several views Instead, use one Action and set it to both the textField and the button

The advantages:

- (as already noted): no coupling between views
- a single location to implement the login logic
- has the notion of enabled, so can be disabled - and with it all views it is bound to . on a locked login

A raw (taking a bit too much responsibility, further separation strongly advised) code snippet, taking over

- grab the valid pins
- register the documentFilter
- validate/lock the login

The Action:

```
public static class LoginAction extends AbstractAction {
    private final AtomicInteger nbTry = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private ArrayList<Integer> pins = readPinsData(new File("bdd.txt"));
    private Document doc;

    public LoginAction(String login, AbstractDocument doc) {
        super(login);
        this.doc = doc;
        doc.setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter(){

            @Override
            public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
                String string =fb.getDocument().getText(0, fb.getDocument().getLength())+text;
                if(string.length() <= 4)
                    super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs); 
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (nbTry.get() > 2) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Pin blocked due to 3 wrong tries");
            setEnabled(false);
            return;
        }
        String passEntered = null;
        try {
            passEntered = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()).replaceAll("\u00A0", "");
        } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (passEntered.length() != 4) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Pin must be 4 digits");
            return;
        }
        boolean authenticated = false;
        ImageIcon imgAngry = new ImageIcon("angry.png");
        ImageIcon imgHappy = new ImageIcon("happy.png");

        if (pins.contains(Integer.parseInt(passEntered))) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Pin correct", "Good Pin", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, imgHappy);
            authenticated = true;
        }

        if (!authenticated) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Pin", "Wrong Pin", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, imgAngry);
            nbTry.incrementAndGet();
        }

    }

}
```

It's usage:

```
PlainDocument document =(PlainDocument)passwordField.getDocument();
LoginAction action = new LoginAction("OK", document);
passwordField.setAction(action);
loginButton.setAction(action);
```