# Using Enter key to use JButton instead of just mouse click?

Tags: java, jframe

How would one bind the "Enter" key on a keyboard to press a JButton? Currently trying to figure this out but have no idea on what to do.

Here is my code for reference. What it's supposed to do is create a guessing game (which it does) but I want to add the ability to press enter to click the "Enter" button (jButtonEnter in this case).

```
package day21;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
//import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;
//import javax.swing.border.*;

public class Day21 extends JApplet implements ActionListener{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //All important Variables
    JTextArea outTextArea = new JTextArea(10,20);
    JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(outTextArea);
    static int GuessMe = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random()*1000);//randomizes the number
    JPanel jPanelTop = new JPanel();
    JPanel jPanelMid = new JPanel();
    JPanel jPanelLow = new JPanel();
    JLabel jLabelTop = new JLabel("Guess a number between 1 and 1000");
    static JTextField jTextFieldInput = new JTextField("Guess Here",25);
    JButton jButtonEnter = new JButton("Enter");
    JButton jButtonReset = new JButton("Reset");
    JButton jButtonClose = new JButton("Close");

    public void init(){

        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
        this.setSize(new Dimension(400, 120));

        //Top Panel
        jPanelTop.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        jPanelTop.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());
        jPanelTop.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(14, 40));
        jPanelTop.setToolTipText("Top Panel");
        this.getContentPane().add(jPanelTop, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        jPanelTop.add(jLabelTop);

        //Middle Panel
        jPanelMid.setBackground(Color.orange);
        jPanelMid.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());
        jPanelMid.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(14, 40));
        jPanelMid.setToolTipText("Center Panel");
        this.getContentPane().add(jPanelMid, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jPanelMid.add(jTextFieldInput);
        jPanelMid.add(jButtonEnter);
        jButtonEnter.addActionListener(this);

        //Lower Panel
        jPanelLow.setBackground(Color.black);
        jPanelLow.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());
        jPanelLow.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(14, 40));
        jPanelLow.setToolTipText("Lower Panel");
        this.getContentPane().add(jPanelLow, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        jPanelLow.add(jButtonReset);
        jPanelLow.add(jButtonClose);
        jButtonClose.addActionListener(this);
        jButtonReset.addActionListener(this);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        double input = 0;
        boolean Error = false;
        String ErrorMSG = "Error: Please Enter a Number";
        try{
            input = Double.parseDouble(jTextFieldInput.getText().trim());;
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException n){
            Error = true;
        }
        if(Error){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, ErrorMSG); //If variable entered is not a number
        }
        String correctAnswer = "Hooray! You guessed Correctly! \n Press Reset to play again";
        String tooHigh = input + " is too high";
        String tooLow = input + " is too low";
        if(!Error){
            if(e.getSource() == jButtonEnter){
                if (input == GuessMe){
                    jPanelLow.setBackground(Color.green);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, correctAnswer);
                }
                if (input > GuessMe){
                    jPanelLow.setBackground(Color.red);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, tooHigh);
                }
                if (input < GuessMe){
                    jPanelLow.setBackground(Color.red);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, tooLow);
                }
            }
        }
        if(e.getSource() == jButtonReset){ 
            Day21.reset(); //runs the reset() method which resets the window back to it's normal state
        }
        if(e.getSource() == jButtonClose){
            System.exit(1); //exits the program
        }
    }

    public static void reset(){

        GuessMe = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random()*1000);//randomizes the number
        jTextFieldInput.setText("Guess Here");
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate? [stackoverflow.com/...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731710/allowing-the-enter-key-to-press-the-submit-button-as-opposed-to-only-using-mo)

Comment: I'm not quite sure but can't you set the focus on the JButton so when you press the enter key it's 'press' the button ? (with the setDefaultButton(yourJButton);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Enter Key and Button](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/25/enter-key-and-button/) for a discussion on this topic and a couple of solutions depending on your exact requirement:

1. use the root pane to set a default button
2. use the UIManager to have focus follow the button
3. use Key Bindings to invoke the default Action

Comment: Ahh thanks! the getRootPane().setDefaultButton(...); seemed to have worked perfectly. I am somewhat new to all this JFrame - JButton - etc. stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Define a method - processEnterButton() and put all the necessary logic there. Call the method from actionPerformed() if the button was clicked. Also define [key binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for the ENTER key and call the processEnterButton() from the binding as well.