# Why this java key bind doesn't work?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, key-bindings

I have a JFrame that simulates a simple celsius to fahrenheit converter.
What I'm trying to do is call the "convert" button action whenever the ENTER key es pressed.

I've tried defining the default button (but it doesn't work).

My code now looks like this:

```
public class TemperatureConverterGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form TemperatureConverterGUI
 */
public TemperatureConverterGUI() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    button_convert = new javax.swing.JButton();
    edittext = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();
    label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    label_resultat = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    resultat = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    button_convert.setText("Converteix");
    button_convert.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            button_convertActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    edittext.setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter(new java.text.DecimalFormat("#0"))));
    edittext.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);
    edittext.setToolTipText("Introdueix un número en Fahrenheit");

    label.setText("Introdueix un número en Fahrenheit:");

    label_resultat.setText("Resultat: ");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(49, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(label_resultat)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(resultat))
                .addComponent(button_convert)
                .addComponent(label)
                .addComponent(edittext, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 212, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(90, 90, 90))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(65, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(label)
            .addGap(12, 12, 12)
            .addComponent(edittext, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(31, 31, 31)
            .addComponent(button_convert)
            .addGap(48, 48, 48)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(label_resultat)
                .addComponent(resultat))
            .addGap(70, 70, 70))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void button_convertActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    int f = Integer.valueOf(edittext.getText());
    int c = VisualTemperatureConverter.FahrenheitToCelsius(f);
    resultat.setText(String.valueOf(c));
}                                              

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TemperatureConverterGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TemperatureConverterGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TemperatureConverterGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TemperatureConverterGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    **TemperatureConverterGUI frame = new TemperatureConverterGUI();

    frame.button_convert.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER,0), "enter");
    frame.button_convert.getActionMap().put("enter", frame.button_convert.getAction());**


    frame.setVisible(true);
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton button_convert;
private javax.swing.JFormattedTextField edittext;
private javax.swing.JLabel label;
private javax.swing.JLabel label_resultat;
private javax.swing.JLabel resultat;
// End of variables declaration
}
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please, see how to create a [mcve]. I fell you could reduce the code length for this specific question drasticly.

Comment: You might found what you want there : [Allowing the “Enter” key to press the submit button, as opposed to only using MouseClick](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13731710/4391450) If so, please do some research first.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing fancy needed, just add this to your edittext setup.

```
edittext.addActionListener((ae)-> button_convertActionPerformed(null));
```

Comment: `edittext.addActionListener((ae)-> button_convertActionPerformed(ae));` would cause less surprises

Comment: true, but I would advise to change the function to:
private void button_convertActionPerformed()