# How to make a JButton appear "as rolled over"

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

A JButton has a different appearance when rolled over. That appearance is different from the "selected" appearance.

I want to display my button "as if" it was rolled over, so that user understands that if he hits the Return key, that button will be triggered.

The problem is not the same as setting the default button, because I am in a situation where I really want to get the user to understand that although he wouldn't expect it, if he hits enter that button will be activated. More details below for those who want some. Setting button as default would make button the default one, but wouldn't be significantly signaling to the user.

In my case the strong enough signal is the appearance that the button has when it is rolled over.

How to do that ?

More details on the situation, for those who want some :

- I have a list of buttons representing options, and a text box at the top, which acts as a filter on the buttons
- when filter is such that only one option remains, hitting return directly clicks that option's button
- in reality user would have had to select the button with tab or arrow, and then hit enter.
- since that shortcut is not obvious I want to signal it to user

Comment: Use [`setDefaultButton()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html#setDefaultButton-javax.swing.JButton-).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allowing the "Enter" key to press the submit button, as opposed to only using MouseClick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731710/allowing-the-enter-key-to-press-the-submit-button-as-opposed-to-only-using-mo)

Comment: @catalinaisland, I edited the question to clear the misunderstanding. These are separate problems, and set default doesn't solve mine.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, what you "really" want, is the `JRootPane#setDefaultButton`, which will highlight the button, in a OS specific manner and if the user presses the default "action" key (Enter in most cases) will call it's `ActionListener`

For example...

[image: MacOS Example]

The "normal" button is just a plain old `JButton`, the `Hacked` sets the `rollOver` to enabled and `Default` has been set as the default button for the `JRootPane`

As you can see, you're suggest fix does nothing on MacOS, don't know what it might do on other platforms

I suggest you have a look at [How to Use Root Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) for more details

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRootPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JButton asDefault = new JButton("Default");

        public TestPane() {
            JButton hack = new JButton("Hacked");
            hack.getModel().setRollover(true);
            hack.setRolloverEnabled(true);
            asDefault.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Defaulted");
                }
            });
            add(new JButton("Normal"));

            add(hack);
            add(asDefault);
        }

        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            JRootPane rootPane = SwingUtilities.getRootPane(this);
            if (rootPane != null) {
                rootPane.setDefaultButton(asDefault);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

So using `button.getModel().setRollover(true);` doesn't work on all platforms and on those platforms it does work on, I suspect the user will simply need to move the mouse through it to return it to normal

Comment: *you're suggest fix does nothing on MacOS* ... well I happen to develop on MacOS, and this fixed my problem. Which is why I posted it here.

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew I'm sorry to say, that based on my example code, it didn't work

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew Can you provide me a runnable example which does work? Because I can't make it work, and I'm not talking about a single line of code, but something I can run and see work, because my example code didn't and it contains your single line

Answer (score -2):

```
button.getModel().setRollover(true);
```

Comment: please explain how your answer solves OP's question.

Comment: Roll-over is not the same as a button press, and is not what the user will expect to see if return causes the same action as a button press. The better solution is to make the button the default button for the JRootPane, so that pressing return causes the button to be actually pressed.

Comment: You're confusing roll over with "default", there are differences which any user use to using the OS will expect. It's also possible that the effect could be removed by the user moving the mouse into and out of the control

Comment: @madprogrammer, I have edited the question to clear misunderstandings. I am not looking for default here. Please let me know if that is still not clear.

Comment: @wasiahmad, I am sincerely trying very hard to understand how that answer doesn't solve the problem, but without success. Can you please explain ? I have edited the question to provide more clarity. Hopefully this helps

Comment: *"I want to display my button "as if" it was rolled over, so that user understands that if he hits the Return key, that button will be triggered."* - simply making the button appear "rolled over" by itself won't make it "default" actionable, and as I said, I could break the solution simply by moving the mouse through it

Comment: @madprogrammer, the question is not how to make the button "default actionable". And second, if user moves the mouse over it, that is not a problem, because then he might as well just click, he doesn't need a parent way to do it through keyboard. Why don't you focus on the question, which was how to make a button appear as rolled over ?

Comment: The question actually does look like it's how to make the button actionable by pressing return, the part where it says `...if he hits the Return key, that button will be triggered.` That behavior would require what @MadProgrammer and @Hovercraft are suggesting. If this is the answer, then I'd imagine the question should read `so the user thinks if he hits the Return key, that the button will be triggered, but in actuality does not`. Still though, this isn't a complete solution for that, as the user can interact with the UI in a way to make the return button actually work, or remove the effect.

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew *"Why don't you focus on the question"* - Because it doesn't answer the question, making the button "roll overed" doesn't make it default capable, the solution you presented doesn't respect how other platforms may make buttons "default actionable", it doens't provide a means for allowing the user press the "action key" (enter on most platforms) to trigger the action, unless the button is focused and it will break if the user tabs through the button or rolls the mouse through it, the whole idea is just broken

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew *"when filter is such that only one option remains, hitting return directly clicks that option's button"* - Describes the functionality of the default actionable button, which can is what `JRootPane#setDefaultButton` will do. *"since that shortcut is not obvious I want to signal it to user"* again describes the default actionable button. I tried your solution, it doesn't work on my platform