# How to hit submit using the Enter key besides the mouseclick?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I have this code

```
valider.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            WebElement c = driver.findElement(By.name("cin"));
            WebElement d = driver.findElement(By.id("dn"));
            WebElement cap = driver.findElement(By.name("cincap"));

            String myPass = String.valueOf(CIN.getPassword());
            String date = daten.getText();
            String capp = code.getText();
            // String ids = "";

            // fill the fields
            c.sendKeys(myPass);
            d.sendKeys(date);
            cap.sendKeys(capp);

            // button valider
            cap.submit();
     }
}
```

How can I allow the “Enter” key to press the submit button ?

I searched and I found a lot of ways 
like

```
 SubmitButton listener = new SubmitButton(textBoxToEnterName);
textBoxToEnterName.addActionListener(listener);
submit.addKeyListener(listener);
```

But I don't know the correct place to put it in my code?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731710/allowing-the-enter-key-to-press-the-submit-button-as-opposed-to-only-using-mo

Comment: You need to add a keylistener, as @mumpitz suggests, read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731710/allowing-the-enter-key-to-press-the-submit-button-as-opposed-to-only-using-mo

Comment: so i added
`if (Event.getSource()==code){
            valider.doClick();
        }`

in the addActionListener class didn't worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by calling `setDefaultButton()` method of `JFrame`'s root pane. Try this example.

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

public class DefaultButton {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
    button1.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("Button 1 action fired"));

    JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
    button2.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("Button 2 action fired"));

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add(button1);
    frame.getContentPane().add(button2);

    frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(button2);

    frame.setBounds(300, 200, 400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain what button1 and button2 do? what i understand is that two button when clicked they will sysout that msg "******* action fired"
if i'm correct, so 

 `frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(button2);`
what that line do?
didn't worked btw, do i need to make a new class for then code that call it ?

Comment: @MJ, did you run my program? Didn't it work (i.e. when you press Enter key, is `button2` action fired)? `setDefaultButton()` is an API provided in Java to get "default button" behavior. Is your button `valider` shown inside a `JFrame`?

Comment: when i hit enter after i write the capthca, it shows in the console "Button 2 action fired"
https://i.imgur.com/u6qj3lm.png

Comment: @MJ, so, have you added `System.out.println("Button 2 action fired");` to the action listener of `valider` button? My code only shows an example of making a button the "default" button. You have to understand my code and apply it to your program.

Comment: finally it worked after i understand the code, thank you very much, i really appreciate it