# How can I use a button and enter key for the same thing? (Java)

Tags: java, swing

So basically I have a button which executes this code:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String textString = text.getText();
    Double textDouble;

    try {    
        textDouble = Double.parseDouble(textString);    
    } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {    
        textDouble = (double) 0;    
    }

    textDouble = textDouble / 2.54;
    inchLabel.setText("The length in inches: " + textDouble);
}
```

I would like to be able to execute that same code when I press the "Enter" key. Any help?

Comment: Seems like you are using AWT. Checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731710/allowing-the-enter-key-to-press-the-submit-button-as-opposed-to-only-using-mo

Comment: That worked, thank you!