# Can't setDefaultButton(btn): no object to call upon

Tags: java, swing, awt

I just want to set certain `JButton` as the default button (i.e. when pressing `ENTER`, it executes its action). Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20494802/587467) and few others, I tried them all:

- `SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(this)`
- `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this)`
- `someJPanelObj.getParent()`
- `SwingUtilities.getRootPane(someJButtonObj)`

But they all return null...

Here is the code:

```
public class HierarchyTest {
    @Test
    public void test(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new CommonPanel());
    }
}
```

CommonPanel:

```
class CommonPanel extends JPanel {
    CommonPanel() {
        JButton btn = new JButton();
        add(btn);

        Window win = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(this); // null :-(
        Window windowAncestor = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this); // null :-(
        Container parent = getParent(); // null :-(
        JRootPane rootPane = SwingUtilities.getRootPane(btn); // null :-(

        rootPane.setDefaultButton(btn); // obvious NullPointerException...
    }
}
```

Comment: @ItamarGreen, I'll try it as soon as I get back to my beloved laptop :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the constructor of `CommonPanel` is called before you add it to the `JFrame`, so it really doesn't have a window, or root parent. You can change your `CommonPanel` to:

```
class CommonPanel extends JPanel {
    JButton btn = new JButton();

    CommonPanel() {

        add(btn);

    }

    public void init() {
        Window win = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(this); // null :-(
        Window windowAncestor = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this); // null
                                                                        // :-(
        Container parent = getParent(); // null :-(
        JRootPane rootPane = SwingUtilities.getRootPane(btn); // null :-(

        rootPane.setDefaultButton(btn); // obvious NullPointerException...

    }
}
```

and then instead of adding a new `commonPanel`, create one:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
CommonPanel panel = new CommonPanel();
frame.add(panel);
panel.init();
```

PS, very good of you to use unit testing, it's an excellent practice.

Comment: It's working, but a bit awkward. I have to call `init()` explicitly. Isn't there some method I can override, like `OnLoaded()`, `OnInitialized()` or something like that, that is automatically called just after the `JPanel` is added to its container?

Comment: @Tar I don't think there is

Comment: @Tar `Isn't there some method I can override, like OnLoaded(), OnInitialized() or something like that, that is automatically called just after the JPanel is added to its container?` - you can add an `AncestorListener` to the panel and handle the `ancestorAdded` event.

Comment: @camickr wait, `ancestorListener` has an `ancestorAdded`? wow I really need to reread the doc

Comment: @ItamarGreen, that's one reason why I keep answering questions. Keep getting tips/hints from other members of the forum. More fun for me than rereading the doc :)

Comment: @camickr good point :P. I guess i'll stick around a bit longer then

Comment: @camickr and ItamarGreen, thanks to you both! still can't get the default button to act like one - [here is the follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41315304/jrootpanesetdefaultbuttonthebutton-does-nothing)...