# JRootPane#setDefaultButton(theButton) does nothing

Tags: java, swing, awt

I want my only `JButton` in the `JFrame` to be the default button and respond to `ENTER` press anywhere in its container.

So I called the `JRootPane#setDefaultButton(theButton)` but nothing happens:

```
package tests;

import org.junit.Test;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class HierarchyTest {
    @Test
    public void test(){
        JDialog win = new JDialog(null, "test", Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        win.setBounds(600,300,400,200);
        CommonPanel panel = new CommonPanel();
        win.add(panel);
        panel.init();
        win.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

`CommonPanel`:

```
package tests;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

class CommonPanel extends JPanel {

    private final JButton btn;
    private final String format = "<html><style> code { font-size: inherit; } </style>" +
            "<body style='font-size:18px'><h1>%s</h1>%s</body></html>";

    CommonPanel() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        final JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
        pane.setContentType("text/html");
        pane.setEditable(false);
        pane.setText(String.format(format, "TITLE", "BODY"));
        add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        btn = new JButton("Change text");
        btn.addActionListener(new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                pane.setText(String.format(format, "Yeaaaaaay!!!", "The eagle has landed!!!"));
            }
        });
        bottomPanel.add(btn);
    }

    void init() {
        JRootPane rootPane = SwingUtilities.getRootPane(btn);
        rootPane.setDefaultButton(btn);
    }
}
```

When I click `btn` the text changes as expected, but pressing `ENTER` does nothing (I must `TAB` my way to the button and only then I can press `ENTER` and get the desired result).

Comment: Even though the JTextPane is not editable, it still starts out with focus, and appears to be swallowing the enter keystroke before it can get to the root pain. Consider adding `pane.setFocusable(false);` to your GUI.

Comment: Post a proper [mcve] when asking a question. That is your code should include the main() method for creating the frame. "org.junit.test" is a third party class that many people won't have. We should be able to copy/paste/compile and test your code without downloading additional libraries.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, please change your comment to an answer so I can accept it.