# How to make key bindings for java.awt.Frame and for all its components?

Tags: java, swing

I used below code in the constructor of `JFrame`. But it's only working when none of the frame components is focused.

```
this.getActionMap().put("doSomething",actions);
getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, Event.CTRL_MASK),"doSomething");
thiis.getActionMap().put("doSomething",actions);`
```

Comment: This question is very confusing because 1) It mentions the FQN of the AWT frame in the title, yet goes on to discuss the Swing frame in the text. 2) Key bindings were never meant for AWT components. 3) It has no question. 4) The code snippet which includes `thiis.getActionMap()..` would never compile. - Voting to close.

Comment: This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67650493/2441655

Answer (score 1):

> But it's only working when none of the frame components is focused.

Correct. You are using the `InputMap` for when the component has focus. If you want the binding to be active even when the component doesn't have focus you need to use a different `InputMap`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial [How Key Bindings Work](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html#maps) for the 3 different InputMap types.

> How to make key bindings for java.awt.Frame and for all its components?

Key Bindings work on Swing components, not AWT components.

You should add the bindings to the `JRootPane` of the `JFrame`:

```
frame.getRootPane().getInputMap(...)...
frame.getRootPane().getActionMap()...
```

Comment: I just want to perform the action when i press ctrl + A even if the jframe component is focused or not .

Comment: @TibinTomy, you can't do this in Java. Swing can only manage events when the frame has focus. You will need to use JNA or JNI (which I know nothing about), if you want to listen for OS events.